# When do multiple awaits make sense?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, task

I have some misunderstanding with c# async/await mechanism.
Is there any essential difference between

```
private async void Init()
{
    await Task.Run(() => Do1());
    await Task.Run(() => Do2());
}
```

and

```
private async void Init()
{
    await Task.Run(() => 
    {
       Do1();
       Do2();
    });
}
```

The only difference I see: in the first sample Do1 and Do2 will be run in different threads while in the second sample - in the same thread. But again, what is the real benefit of it and when I should prefer the 1st approach over the second one and vice versa?

EDIT: The second case

What is the difference between

```
private async void Init()
{
    await Task.Run(() => Do1());
    Do3();
}
```

and

```
private async void Init()
{
    await Task.Run(() => 
    {
       Do1();
       Do3();
    });
}
```

Comment: In your specific case the second approach is better. Because any way after Do1,  Do2 is going to be executed so no difference in results. task.run adds some overhead in first approach. Also note that in both cases Do1 runs first and after it finishes Do2 starts

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary in the first situation, do they run one after the other as the task is being started then we await straight away? ie would they both run at the same time if they were assigned to variable and started both before awaiting the first?

Comment: Yes. If you store them in variable and then await they would run individually but now because there is await right after creating tasks they start one after another @Dhunt

Comment: So the main difference is Task creation overhead? Ok. Please tell me one more thing: what if I have no second await at all, just a regular continuation method (Please, see my EDIT). What is the difference then?

Comment: @Sergey *never* use `async void` unless you want to implement an asynchronous event handler. There's no way to await an `async void` method *or catch any exceptions thrown*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is:

First example:

- You queue `Do1` on a threadpool thread and asynchronously wait for it to complete, then do the exact same with `Do2`. These may run on different threads.
- You queue `Do1` and `Do2` to execute synchronously one after the other on the same thread pool thread.

Second example:

- Queue `Do1` on the threadpool and asynchronously wait for it to complete, then invoke `Do3` synchronously.
- This is exactly the same as the second part of the first example.

Note that when you `await`, you asynchronously wait for the operation to complete, hence unless the method finishes it won't execute the next line of code.

I'm assuming you're asking yourself if one is preferable to the other, and as in most cases, it depends. If you're running inside a console app, and you're going to asynchronously wait for `Do1` to complete anyway, then pass both methods to the same `Task.Run` invocation. If you're planning on doing this in a place where synchronization matters, such as a GUI application, then any operation which needs to interact with UI controls should be invoked on the UI thread.

Another option which is more common is when you have two operations which are independent of each other and you want to start them together and wait for both to complete. This is where you'd use `Task.WhenAll`:

```
var firstDo = Task.Run(() => Do1());
var secondDo = Task.Run(() => Do2());
await Task.WhenAll(firstDo, secondDo);
```

**Side note:**

Do not use `async void` in asynchronous methods with no return value, that is what `async Task` is for. The former is only meant to allow compatibility with event handlers, where I'm assuming this isn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

- if `Do1()` and `Do2()` are independent from each other you should run them separately. This is even more important if they're long-running / blocking processes
- on the other hand if they're related and the first one does some operations that are required by the other then it is better to run them in one thread to reduce the threading overhead. After all, you know in advance they need to run sequentially

Comment: In both cases they run one afther another. The only difference I see: in the 1st case they will be run each in their own thread. But not concurrently! Thread for the 2nd task will be started only after 1st task finish. So I don't see any essential difference between the cases except some performance overhead.